# how to run a scrapy project using crawl command

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I'm walking through the Scrapy tutorial. I've been able to create my project by using windows7. my scrapy is installed in the path like this:

```
C:\Program Files\python2.7\scripts.
```

I construct a project called yuan by scrapy startproject yuan,
but when I try to run the project by scrapy crawl yuan, there is an error:"unknown command crawl".

I tried to execute it in the"yuan" project where I can see the file "scrapy.cfg", 
`C:\Program Files\python2.7\scipts\yuan\scrapy crawl yuan,` there is another error:

"scrapy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

I am sure I have changed my path environmental variables, I have added

`"C:\Program Files\python2.7\scripts" and "C:\Program Files\python2.7"`

into the path variables.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: do you have scrapy installed

Comment: yes, I have installed scrapy, I can successfully construct a scrapy project

Comment: first, you can create projects out of scripts folder. Use scrapy startproject yuan. Then cd yuan. Then, scrapy crawl yuan

Answer (score 3):

**Global commands:**

```
startproject
settings
runspider
shell
fetch
view
version
```

**Project-only commands:**

```
crawl
check
list
edit
parse
genspider
deploy
bench
```

Scrapy has [two differen](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html)t type of commands as listed above.

In your case `Crawl` is a project only command.  So you have to navigate to your project and execute the `crawl` command.

```
Cd <your project>

scrapy crawl <Project name>
```

Comment: well, I have already solved this problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @Jacqueline how did you solve your problem? can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

cd C:\Program Files\python2.7\scipts\yuan

```
scrapy crawl yuan
```

If you run crawl command outside of a project, scrapy will raise "unknown command crawl" error.